# How can I notify awaiting Task from another thread to complete?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

Consider following pseudocode:

Thread `#1`

```
var task = new Task<int>();
this.AwaitingTask = task;
return await task;
```

Thread `#2`

```
this.AwaitingTask.Complete(16);
```

This way, `#2` thread would pass return value (int) and notify that Task is completed. So the `#1` thread would know to continue execution.

Is it possible to implement? And how? I'm looking for closest idea that would work in similiar way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have to implement it. It is already shipped with name 
[`TaskCompletionSource<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Thread 1**

```
var completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
this.CompletionSource= completionSource;
return await completionSource.Task;
```

**Thread 2**

```
this.CompletionSource.SetResult(16);
```

Comment: Woah, I almost guessed it.